# Adjective for person who aggressively informs unneeded things to us

Tags: word-choice

I am looking for an adjective to represent a person behavior in which she/he aggressively informs us unnecessary things.

For example, during a conversation, she/he changes the topic with different thing that we are not interested in. Another example, someone tells what we already knows.

Answer (score 2):

Though it's not an adjective, a [*snoutband*](http://definithing.com/snoutband/) is:

> someone who constantly interrupts conversation, typically only to contradict or correct someone

Answer (score 1):

Discursive means:

> digressing from subject to subject, relating to discourse

which relates to someone who continually changes the topic.

Someone who is *loquacious* [tends to talk too much](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/loquacious). That person could also be a [*rambler*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rambler), and we could describe his style of speaking as verbose.